# The javascript code I'm using is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code fragment that is asking to fade out in 2 seconds:

```
<fieldset id="question-2">
   <p>
      <label>Question 2</label>
   </p>
   <p>Make the word "Disappear" disappear after two seconds.</p>
   <p class="target">Disappear</p>
   <p class="output"></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="question-3">
   <p>
      <label>Question 3</label>
   </p>
   <p>Make the word "Fade" fade after two seconds.</p>
   <p class="target">Fade</p>
   <p class="output"></p>
</fieldset>
```

I used this to fade out the targeted words:

```
$("#question-2.target").fadeOut(2000);
$("#question-3.target").fadeOut(2000);
```

This is not working. Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're forgetting a space after the question ID in your jQuery selector. So instead of what you have currently, I think you should use this:

```
$("#question-2 .target").fadeOut(2000);
$("#question-3 .target").fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) your code might be executing before the elements are even created. wrap your script in

```
$(function(){
    //...put code here...
});
```

this will assure your code is executed after the elements are already created.

2) you need to put a space between the selector's id and class parts, otherwise it will search for all elements with this id and class in the same element. to search for child elements, put a space:

**UPDATE**

**if you want the word "disappear" to disappear after 2 seconds and not fade out like the other word, you need to set a time out for 2 seconds as follows:**

```js
setTimeout(makeDisapper,2000);
$("#question-3 .target").fadeOut(2000);

function makeDisapper(){
    $("#question-2 .target").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="question-2">
    <p>
        <label>Question 2</label>
    </p>
    <p>Make the word "Disappear" disappear after two seconds.</p>
    <p class="target">Disappear</p>
    <p class="output"></p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="question-3">
    <p>
        <label>Question 3</label>
    </p>
    <p>Make the word "Fade" fade after two seconds.</p>
    <p class="target">Fade</p>
    <p class="output"></p>
</fieldset>
```